# Display all instances of a record if record modified within date range

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm writing a report in SSRS and I need to display all instances of a record if that record has been changed on the selected date.

For example:
User wants to see if a record was modified on 3/3/2015.  Right now it is returning

```
Record 1
Modified 3/3/2015
```

What I need to return is:

```
Record 1
Modified 2/1/2015
Modified 2/9/2015
Modified 3/3/2015
```

Generally speaking they will be reviewing for changes made the previous day, but they need to see all changes made to records that have been changed on the date they are reviewing.  If they were reviewing for 3/3/2015 they wouldn't want to see a record that had only been modified on 3/2/3015.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` or `in` for this:

```
select r.*
from records r
where r.recordid in (select r2.recordid
                     from records r2
                     where r2.recordid = r.recordid and r2.modified = '2015-03-03'
                    );
```